# Why the need for safe wakeup and clone methods in doctrine 2?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

The documentation warns a few times about ensuring wakeup and clone implementations on Doctrine 2 entities, e.g.:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/implementing-wakeup-or-clone.html

It doesn't say why, however... I presume it has something to do with not messing with Doctrine's Entity Manager and the in-memory-cache it might maintain, but a cursory dive into the (enormous) code base doesn't say much more, nor did a quick search of the users list.

Might anyone knowledgeable with the Doctrine internals know precisely why Doctrine 2 needs safe wakeup and clone methods on entities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doctrine 2 needs to convert data fetched from the database into entities (php objects). This process is called hydration.

Doctrine 2 doesn't use the traditional method of using the `new` operator (thus constructing a class), but it uses the following method:

- It builds a string which represents a serialized empty version of your class.
- It unserializes that string to make it an actual object. This is why you need to safely implement `__wakeup`.
- It stores that object as prototype.

This process is done once for each entity class.

Then whenever it needs to hydrate an entity, it will clone the prototype. This is why you need to safely implement `__clone`.

This is all done a small method `newInstance()` in [ClassMetadataInfo](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L866).

The advantage of doing this is that the constructor isn't used when a new entity is hydrated. That leaves the developer free to do anything he/she wants in the constructor (including using parameters).

**update**

The reason why you need to safely implement the `__wakeup` and `__clone` methods is this:

Because Doctrine 2 unserializes and clones entities when it needs to hydrate them, those methods will get called. But when Doctrine 2 does this, the entities will *not* have any data set (not even the identifier(s)). The data will be set afterwards.

So when you implement them in such a way that your logic is only performed when the entity *does* have the identifier(s), you are sure that your logic is only performed when *you* unserialize or clone the entity, *not* when Doctrine 2 does it.

Comment: I've added a follow-up answer to highlight the reason Doctrine does this.

Answer (score 2):

Jasper's answer nails the precise reason, but it doesn't give the background — as in *why* Doctrine is proceeding to unserialize and clone entities.

The rational for doing so is to allow entities to define whatever constructor they want, as explained in this blog post:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/21/doctrine-2-give-me-my-constructor-back.html

> At ConFoo 2010 during my presentation, someone asked about the constructor of entities in Doctrine 2 and whether or not it could be used. I think this is something worth writing about since in Doctrine 1 this was not possible. The constructor was hi-jacked from you and used internally by Doctrine.
>
> In Doctrine 2 it is possible to define the constructor in your entity classes and is not required to be a zero argument constructor! That’s right, Doctrine 2 never instantiates the constructor of your entities so you have complete control!
>
> This is possible due to a small trick which is used by two other projects, [php-object-freezer](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/831-Freezing-and-Thawing-PHP-Objects.html) and Flow3. The gist of it is we store a prototype class instance that is unserialized from a hand crafted serialized string where the class name is concatenated into the string. The result when we unserialize the string is an instance of the class which is stored as a prototype and cloned everytime we need a new instance during hydration.
>
> Have a look at the method responsible for this:

```
<?php
public function newInstance()
{
    if ($this->_prototype === null) {
        $this->_prototype = unserialize(sprintf('O:%d:"%s":0:{}', strlen($this->name), $this->name));
    }
    return clone $this->_prototype;
}
```